# Digerati IQ test

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

This question contains spoilers.
After making the Digerati IQ test (http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.digerati.iqtest) there are three questions where I still don't know how they come to the correct (green) answer. Can somebody explain?

[image]
My reasoning: a big circle cannot have an open side, but aside from that, the left column has the open side on the bottom, the center column has the open side on the left and the right column has the open side on the right. So my answer (B) makes perfectly sense to me, but apparently it's wrong. How is (E) more logical?

[image]
No clue

[image]
I have some explanation to come to (B), but apparently it's wrong.

(If it should be three different questions let me know. I just didn't want to spam the board.)

Comment: They say they want them each in different questions, but most of the time they won't close it for multiples.

Comment: 1 can be narrowed down to B and E, as there is one of each shape in each row/column and also one white dot per row/column, not sure why E not B. 2 no idea, but 3 I've got - each shape is the other two shapes in the row or column, whichever you choose, added together and the thick white lines cancel out